# Web Audio playing back in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, audio, web-audio-api

Firefox seems to be processing the audio but it won't play it back. This exact code works fine with Chrome. I'm seeing no errors from the console so I'm really at a loss. I'm thinking it has something to do with audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(audio); but I'm not sure. Anyone know why this audio won't play back in FF but will in Chrome? I'm running FF 27 right now.

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
var init = 0;
var nextTime = 0;
var audioStack = [];

function toArrayBuffer(buffer) {
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    return ab;
}

socket.on('stream', function(data) {
    audioStack.push(data);
    //if ((init!=0) || (audioStack.length > 10)) { // make sure we put at least 10 chunks in the buffer before starting
            init++;
            scheduleBuffers();
    //}
});

function scheduleBuffers() {
    while (audioStack.length) {

        var data  = toArrayBuffer(audioStack.shift().data);
        var audio = [];
        audData = new Int16Array(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < audData.length; i++) {
            audio[i] = (audData[i]>0)?audData[i]/32767:audData[i]/32768; // convert buffer to within the range -1.0 -> +1.0
        }

        var source      = context.createBufferSource();
        var audioBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, audio.length , 44100);
        source.buffer   = audioBuffer;

        audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(audio);

        source.connect(context.destination);
        if (nextTime == 0)
            nextTime = context.currentTime + 0.05;  /// add 50ms latency to work well across systems - tune this if you like
        source.start(nextTime);
        console.log('length: '+source.buffer.duration);
        nextTime+=source.buffer.duration; // Make the next buffer wait the length of the last buffer before being played
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you mind linking to ac omplete web page showing the problem?

Comment: Here ya go: https://github.com/grkblood13/web-audio-stream/tree/master/socketio/socketio-pcm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at this code:

```
    source.buffer   = audioBuffer;
    audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(audio);
```

Can you try changing the order of these two lines?  In other words, first set the channel data for audioBuffer and then assign it to source.buffer.  Does that fix the problem for you?

Comment: yep, that fixes the problem! Would this be considered a bug due to the differences in results between browsers?

Comment: This *will* cause problems in the future in Chrome as well.  This is a relatively recent change to the spec to deal with potential race conditions.

Comment: Yes.  The issue here is that when you set the buffer attribute on an AudioBufferSourceNode, we neuter the underlying array buffer in the AudioBuffer object being used at the right hand sign of the assignment, in order to make it impossible for future modifications to the array buffer to affect what the audio thread sees.  As Chris mentioned, this is done to prevent potential race conditions.

Your code is relying on modifications to the AudioBuffer's underlying array buffer after setting the buffer attribute.  Hope this helps.